# After upgrading angular 4 to 5, Api's not working and throws console error

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, angular

My localhost (hosted in IIS) was working just fine including internal .net (C#) service endpoint.
Recently I upgraded angular 4 to 5, I tested my endpoint from postman and it works. If I debug from visual studio instead of IIS , it sometime works and sometime not (you may be thinking weird here and so do I).
I am getting below console error and network call.

[image]. 
[image]

And I thought this is something with CORS which I have already had on my project and below is snapshot of it. (But again this was working on angular 4 project)

[image]
and before asking this question, i did couple of thing like:

1) npm cache clear

2) remove node_modules

2) npm install

3) updated Http to HttpCLient and HttpModule to HttpClientModule

so my angular service looks like this:

```
  private apiUrl_getReport = 'https://localhost/ServiceAPI/api/report';

 httpOptions = {
     headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
    })
  };


 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

 getReports(): Observable<ReportGetData[]> {
    return this.http.get<ReportGetData[]>(`${this.apiUrl_getReport}`);
  }
```

To resolve this, any insight from you will be grateful to me.

Comment: Have you converted to the new HttpClient or are you still using the legacy Http API?

Comment: Have you done this? https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com

Comment: @RandyCasburn yes, I have re-implemented Http to HttpClient and HttpModule to HttpClientModule.  I have edited question.

Comment: Does this error occur in incognito mode or in browsers other than chrome?

Comment: @RandyCasburn I tried on incognito mode also,  persist of same issue.

Comment: OK. The next thing to check/test/do is to go through your SSL certificate store and remove the certificate for that site from your store. That all depends on whether you are on windows or Mac or linux etc. Once that is done, then try to load the site again.

Comment: @RandyCasburn I accept your comment as answer.

Comment: Awesome. Please accept my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. The next thing to check/test/do is to go through your SSL certificate store and remove the certificate for that site from your store. That all depends on whether you are on windows or Mac or linux etc. Once that is done, then try to load the site again.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem yesterday and it boiled down to a package that had incompatibility issues in Angular 5 recently: webpack.

Try the steps [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8333). You may have to repeat the step you did for clearing the cache.